# What is the fastest a generator can be completed?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

Let's say that 4 survivors are all working on the same gen with purple toolboxes with the best add-ons (not including brand new part) and all of the best perks to complete the generator as fast as possible. How fast would that generator be completed?

---

Edit: Here's what I could find to help

4 survivors working on a gen takes a base of **28.57 seconds**

A purple toolbox **increases repair speed by 25%** (There is no listing for the add-ons)

Prove Thy Self **increases work speed by 10% for all survivors near by** (This perk can't stack so it would only be 10% for each survivor)

Resilience **increases repair speed by 9%** while injured

Spine Chill **increases repair speed by 6%** while the killer is looking at you

---

Edit 2: All of the speed increases combined would give a **200% speed increase** but with all 4 survivors working on the same gen you get around a **30% speed decrease** Giving you a ***170% increase to working speed***

Comment: "4 survivors working on a gen takes a base of 28.57 seconds"  Out of curiosity, where are you getting this number?

Comment: From the fourms. 1 person - 80 seconds  2 people - 44.44 seconds  3 people - 33.33 seconds  4 people - 28.57 seconds. https://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I did this right but...

All of the speed increases would put it at a **200% speed increase** but there is a **30% efficiency decrease** with all of the survivors working on the gen giving a **170% speed increase**

[ (25% + 10% + 9% + 6%) *4 = 200% - 30% = 170%]

Which would mean you could do the gen in around **13 seconds**.

This can also be increased with great skill checks but wouldn't do very much with you doing more than 10% of the gen a second and Great Skill Checks only giving a 1% increase to progression. Overall if all 4 people were to get skill checks as fast as they can and all of them hit great skill checks you could probably get that down to around **10 seconds**

Comment: "Which would mean you could do the gen in 9.52 seconds." Why?  Also, are you considering that each survivor has an efficiency penalty when multiple survivors are working on the same generator?

Comment: I forgot the efficiency penalty would change more than the base time. I'll do some more work to figure out the exact answer.